# Get row with highest number from one column and join rows with same value from another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table with a similar structure as follows...

```
| version | col1 | col2 |
| ------- | ---- | ---- |
| 1       | val1 | 3243 |
| 2       | val1 | 7542 |
| 3       | val1 | 7322 |
| 4       | val1 | 8632 |
| 1       | val2 | 1948 |
| 2       | val2 | 0491 |
| 1       | val3 | 6282 |
| 1       | val4 | 9283 |
| 2       | val4 | 8272 |
| 3       | val4 | 0029 |
| 4       | val4 | 1279 |
```

I am trying to find a row with the highest number value from `version` and display all the rows with the same value from `col1` as the first row. My desired output would be as follows...

```
| version | col1 | col2 |             | version | col1 | col2 |
| ------- | ---- | ---- |             | ------- | ---- | ---- | 
| 1       | val1 | 3243 |             | 1       | val4 | 9283 |
| 2       | val1 | 7542 |      OR     | 2       | val4 | 8272 |
| 3       | val1 | 7322 |             | 3       | val4 | 0029 |
| 4       | val1 | 8632 |             | 4       | val4 | 1279 |
```

The final set of rows aren't important. It's only important to choose one row that would contain the highest version number and be joined with other rows containing the same `col1` value.

My idea was to find the first row using:

`SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM table ORDER BY version DESC) a`

and join the other rows but I don't know how to go about it.

Can anyone please help me write a query that would achieve one of these results?

Comment: As there are *two* rows with the "highest" value (`4`) for `col1` how do you determine which should be returned?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the logic you want to implement. See if you can [edit] your question to include some detailed explanation. Also why do you have alternative desired results?

Comment: @PM77-1 I've updated by question. Hopefully it is a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out...

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT TOP(1) * FROM table ORDER BY version DESC) b
ON a.col1 = b.col1
ORDER BY a.version
```